# Restart fromjQuery each

Tags: jquery, each

I am doing a jQuery slideshow and going to preload images and then add them to another array. But however I need to get the slideshow working properly. I included fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/z6qkH/.

So you might ask what's wrong, the slideshow works? yes, but I need to make it optimal because right now it almost crashes because of some loop issues? I am running the SlideShow() function after the foreach loop (I thought) but this doesn't work because I get huge lag in the start. I want to run this method from start again. Do I need to use a for loop for this?

```
        var img_load = new Array();

     img_load[0] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/KobO2FZYMtA/mqdefault.jpg';
     img_load[1] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/6FjdbO-CGC4/mqdefault.jpg';
     img_load[2] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/h-_cN3_zGuI/mqdefault.jpg';
     img_load[3] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/rPf0CTptt8o/mqdefault.jpg';

        /**
         * Foreach loop
         */
             function SlideShow()
             {
                $.each(img_load, function(i, val) { 
                $("#sImage").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
                /**
                 * Queue function will place the event in queue
                 * Changing image src after the above animate function is completed
                 */
                $("#sImage").queue(function(){
                    $("#sImage").attr("src", val);
                    $("#sImage").dequeue();                
                });

                $("#sImage").attr("src", val).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);   

                /**
                 * Queue function will place the event in queue
                 * Here, queue function is used to hold the changing image for 1 second display
                 */            
                $("#sImage").queue(function(){                 
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#sImage").dequeue();
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });
            SlideShow(); // Not good for some reason. I want to loop from start
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I would not have really gone along this approach for a carousel, but there are millions off tutorials online so I wont go into it on this question.
Your problem is you firing your whole function on a loop which then again fires the function etc.

The quickest fix for you would be to check for the array length and only fire it at the end.

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/z6qkH/2/

var img_load = new Array();

```
 img_load[0] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/KobO2FZYMtA/mqdefault.jpg';
 img_load[1] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/6FjdbO-CGC4/mqdefault.jpg';
 img_load[2] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/h-_cN3_zGuI/mqdefault.jpg';
 img_load[3] = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/rPf0CTptt8o/mqdefault.jpg';

    /**
     * Foreach loop
     */
         function SlideShow()
         {
            var count = 0;
            $.each(img_load, function(i, val) {
            $("#sImage").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
            /**
             * Queue function will place the event in queue
             * Changing image src after the above animate function is completed
             */
            $("#sImage").queue(function(){
                $("#sImage").attr("src", val);
                $("#sImage").dequeue();                
            });

            $("#sImage").attr("src", val).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);   

            /**
             * Queue function will place the event in queue
             * Here, queue function is used to hold the changing image for 1 second display
             */            
            $("#sImage").queue(function(){                 
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#sImage").dequeue();
                    if((img_load.length-1) == count){
                        SlideShow();
                    }
                           count++;
                }, 1000);
            });
        });



    }

$(document).ready(function()
{
    SlideShow();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks I actually did try if(img_load.length == i) in the end for some testing but I see what you mean. Thanks so much for the great reply. About the wrong approach for this with carousel... that is such a shame. I will look into a tutorial and see what the issues is. Thank you!